# Set default value for CfnParameter when left empty in CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a CDK project and I need to have input parameters and some of them have to be optional.
In my code I need to have a value in any case, so I'm looking a way to set a value if the user left the field empty.
I found some things with `Fn.conditionIf` and `CfnCondition` but I don't understand how to use them to achieve what I want.

Here is what I have:

```ts
const param1 = new CfnParameter(this, "Param1", {
    type: "String",
    description: "Myparam",
});
```

Later on my code I'm getting the value and here I need to set something if is empty:

```ts
var myObj = {
    myParamFromUser: param1.valueAsString,
};
```

If I use `default` value field, that value is displayed on the Console and the field has already the value. I want to have the field empty on the Console.

How to set a value if param1 is empty?

Answer (score 1):

I made it work:

```
const myCfnParam = new CfnParameter(this, "Param", {
        type: "String",
        description:
          "Input param",
      });
const myCondition = new CfnCondition(this, 'Condition', { expression: Fn.conditionEquals(myCfnParam, '') });
const myValue= Fn.conditionIf(myCondition.logicalId, 'MY_STRING', myCfnParam.valueAsString).toString();
```